# Convert Unix time to Datetime in Apex Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, apex-trigger

I have requirement to to store the timestamp returned from the response to Salesforce DateTime. But the timestamp returned is in Unix format.
How do I convert it to DateTime in Salesforce using apex?

Answer (score 2):

This is a super old question, but I found an answer.

I was grabbing some data from a REST API that had a unix timestamp as the modified date. I needed to convert the unix timestamp into a Datetime object using Apex in Salesforce.

Also, make sure that the utcTime variable is cast as an Integer as Datetime.addSeconds() wants an Integer.

```
utcTime = 1376986594;
createdDate = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
createdDate.addSeconds(utcTime);
System.debug('DateTime: ' + createdDate);
```

Comment: Next time post the relevant snippet from that link. Your Link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

Try integer.valueOf instead of long.valueOf

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I have tried using integar.valueOf but it does not help!!